# Why exit status of command "ls" is difference between bash and csh shell?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

Why `exit status` is different between *bash* and *csh shell*?, In [`ls` man:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)

```
Exit status:
       0      if OK,

       1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),

       2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line
              argument).
```

In order to test `exit status` of the command `ls`, let's say we have single file called `ss` saved in a folder. Let's list this file based on the status of it's characters using the wildcard `?`

In csh Shell:

```
ls -d ss
ss

ls -d s?
ss

ls -d ?s
ss

ls -d ?z
ls: No match.

ls -d ?z | echo $?  #check exit status
0
```

In Bash:

```
ls -d ss
ss

ls -d s?
ss

ls -d ?s
ss

ls -d ?z
ls: cannot access ?z: No such file or directory

ls -d ?z | echo $?  #check exit status
2
```

It is the same command `ls`, but the exit status is different between `csh shell` and `bash`:

- In csh shell the exit status is `0`
- In bash the exit status is `2`

Now, the questions are:

1) Why the same command `ls` has difference exit status between bash and csh shell?

2) What is the importance of this difference in the command behaviour under bash and csh shell?

Comment: I always thought `bash` **IS** a shell ("bourne again shell")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your `ls -d ?z | echo $?` in Bash is not measuring what you think it is. The pipeline all starts at once, and parameter expansion happens even before that, so `echo $?` is printing the return code of the *previous* command, not the one before the pipe. Under csh, it's not even doing that. That output is meaningless. If you run them as separate commands: `ls -d ?z ; echo $?` you will get informative output about what the actual exit code was.

`sh -c 'exit 53'` will work as a command for testing whether you're really getting the exit code from where you wanted.

---

Second, though you haven't told us, the error in your first example sounds like csh so I'll assume it's that. In that case, **`ls -d ?z` is not running `ls` at all**; the shell's wildcard expansion is failing and an error ("`No match`") has been reported, inhibiting the command from running. [Bash, by default, passes non-matching globs through literally](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion): it runs `ls '?z'`, in effect, and you get an error from `ls` because that file doesn't exist. Regardless, the error code reported was from the previous line.

So the `ls` command, when it ran, had the same behaviour in all cases, it just wasn't running in the first place some of the time.

---

You can change Bash's (frankly, bad) behaviour [with `shopt -s failglob`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shopt). It will then error out when a glob does not match:

```
/tmp$ ls ?z
ls: cannot access '?z': No such file or directory
/tmp$ shopt -s failglob
/tmp$ ls ?z
bash: no match: ?z
```

The first will have an exit code of 2, from `ls`, and for the second `$?` will be 1, from Bash itself.

Comment: very nice explanation.. make sense. Many thanks ;-)

Comment: It's probably `tcsh`. In `csh` (and `tcsh`) the exit status is in `$status`. But in `tcsh`, `$?` is also supported as an alternative.

Comment: Note the difference thoug: with `bash -O failglob` (or `zsh` or `fish`) the command is cancelled if any of the globs fail to match while in `csh`, `zsh -o cshnullglob` and pre-Bourne Unix shells, the command is cancelled if none of the globs match any file.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas. thank you for the highlights!